# Adding two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have two subspaces:

$$W_1 = \{(x, 3x) : x\in \Bbb R \}$$ and

$$W_2 = \{(2x, 0): x\in \Bbb R \}$$

How do I get $W_1 + W_2$? 
I tried simply adding a sample vector from each, i.e. $$ (1, 3) + (2, 0) = (3, 3)$$ but I don't think this makes sense since this new vector doesn't fit it $W_1$ nor $W_2$....

Comment: So the answer is simply ℝ x ℝ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$W_1+W_2$ is by definition the set of **all** vectors $w_1+w_2$ such that $w_1\in W_1$ and $w_2\in W_2$. You have $$W_1=\big\{(x,3x):x\in\Bbb R\big\}=\big\{x(1,3):x\in\Bbb R\big\}$$ and $$W_2=\big\{(2x,0):x\in\Bbb R\big\}=\big\{x(2,0):x\in\Bbb R\big\}\;,$$ so you’re looking at all vectors of the form $x(1,3)+y(2,0)$ for $x,y\in\Bbb R$. Every vector in $W_1$ can be written in this form (with $y=0$), and every vector in $W_2$ can be written in this form as well, but you can’t expect every vector in $W_1+W_2$ to belong to $W_1$ or $W_2$. In fact, this occurs if and only if one of the subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ is a subspace of the other.

**Note:** you must combine each vector in $W_1$ with **every** vector in $W_2$, so you need to allow the coefficients $x$ and $y$ to be different; that’s why I have $x$ and $y$ and not $x$ and $x$.

Comment: So is there any way to explicitly describe $W_1 + W_2$ as its own entity or can you only describe it as the sum of two other spaces?

Comment: @Imray: In this case it has a very simple description. The vectors $(1,3)$ and $(2,0)$ are linearly independent, so $W_1+W_2$ is ... ?

Comment: .......$\Bbb R^2$ ?

Comment: @Imray: That’s right: it’s the whole space.

Comment: :)  What about if these did not span a whole space, i.e. two subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$ that didn't span the whole space?

Comment: @Imray: Then you’d simply have to find a basis for the sum.

Comment: wow this is really good, thank you brian!! i think i get it... even though i get the post, i don't get how they made $W_2$, cause i see that $W_1$ comes from $y=3x$, but $W_2$ doesn't make sense cause $y=0$, and $x=2x$??

Comment: @beginner: I’m glad that it helped. $W_2$ is actually just the $x$-axis. Take any point $\langle a,0\rangle$ on the $x$-axis. Now let $x=\frac{a}2$. Then $\langle a,0\rangle=\langle 2x,0\rangle$. You can think of it as the result of applying the linear transformation $T(\vec v)=2\vec v$ to the $x$-axis: everything is stretched out twice as far from the origin, but the transformation carries the $x$-axis onto itself.

Answer (score 3):

Carefully note that **for any two sets** (not only for subspaces) $S$ & $T$, $S+T=${$s+t:s\in S, t\in T$}. Thus your sample vector viz $(3,3)$ is just a single element of $W_1+W_2$. You need to accommodate all such in $W_1+W_2$. Thus what should be the general form of a vector in $W_1+W_2$? Isn't it $(x,3x)+(2y,0)$ for $x,y\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: So the space $W_1+W_2$ is $(x+2y, 3x)$ ??

Comment: Yes. But for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: In the example I gave, what is $W1∪W2$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the way. You have to add *all* pairs of $W_1$ and $W_2$.
So, formally
$$W_1+W_2=\{w_1+w_2\mid w_1\in W_1\text{ and }w_2\in W_2\}.$$
For example the sum of two lines (both containing the origo) in the space is the plane they span.

Anyway, it is worth to mention, that $W_1+W_2$ is the *smallest subspace* that contains $W_1\cup W_2$.

Comment: Aren't $W_1+W_2$ and $W_1\cup W_2$ the same thing?

Comment: Absolutely not. Note that $W_1\bigcup W_2$ is not necessarily a subspace but $W_1+W_2$ is.

Comment: In the example I gave, what is $W_1\cup W_2$?

Comment: It's just the two lines $y=3x$ & the $x$-axis whereas $W_1+W_2$ is the entire $\mathbb R^2$. Can you give the reason behind it?